# Cannot load option values in select in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When search_dropdown values are set, using the selected value as the index need to set the value of filterText dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="filter in filtersArray track by $index">
                <select name="search_dropdown"
                        ng-model="search_dropdown[filter]"
                        class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Filter Field</option>
                    <option data-ng-repeat="t in list_fields" value="{{t.field}}">{{t.displayName}}</option>
                </select>
            <select name="filterText" class="form-control" ng-model="filterText[filter]">
                <option value="">Select Filter Text</option>
                <option data-ng-repeat="t in list['{{search_dropdown[filter]}}'] track by $index" value="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
            </select>
```

`search_dropdown = ['name','description']` and the value of
 `list['name'] = ['A','B'] and list['description'] = ['C','D']` where list is an object.

```
<option data-ng-repeat="t in list['{{search_dropdown[filter]}}'] 
track by $index" value="{{t}}">{{t}}</option>
```

Here how to set the value of filterText dropdown with A,B when name is selected in search_dropdown and C,D when description is selected?

Comment: Please make a plunker and link it

Comment: Did you try it without the braces `t in list [search_dropdown[filter]]`?

Comment: Thank you @Brakebein, it worked!!